# Can <cfxml> be created in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, xml-parsing, cfml

Is there a way to use  in cfscript? I can't find a simple example online. I have a .cfc file built using cfscript and I'm trying to use cfxml.

I have a XMLContent variable and I tried the code below.

```
cfxml variable="myXML" {
    WriteOutPut(#XMLContent#);
}
```

It is returning: `function keyword is missing in FUNCTION declaration.` in my cfxml declaration.

Comment: I think `variable="myXML"` needs to be in braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this.

```
cfxml (variable="myXML") {
    WriteOutPut(XMLContent);
}
```

But I suspect you are trying to

```
  <cfscript>
  myXML = XMLParse(XMLContent);
  </cfscript>
```